# Trying to do sentiment analysis with "afinn" dictionary

Tags: r, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to sentiment analysis in my project and want to use different dictionaries. Here I am trying to use "afinn" but I am getting this error. I am able to use "bing" dictionary but not others.

```
> get_sentiments("afinn") %>% count(sentiment)
Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘textdata’
```

Comment: `tidytext` now has a dependency on `textdata` to download some sentiment dictionaries: https://juliasilge.com/blog/sentiment-lexicons/   Try `install.packages("textdata")`